# Downloading BIN file gets extra characters appended to the file during download

Tags: php

I am getting a hex string from a database table, creating a bin file, storing that bin file in a TEMP folder, and then downloading the file. When I look at the bin file in the TEMP folder, all of the data is correct. When I look at the file after the download, the following somehow got appended to the end of the file -> 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d

Code is

```
$binfile = hex2bin($bin_file);
$file_w = fopen("/var/www/html/temp/".$full_name, "w+");
fwrite($file_w, $binfile);
fclose($file_w);

$file_name = "/var/www/html/temp/".$full_name;
header('Pragma: public');   
header('Expires: 0');       
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file_name));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($file_name);
```

What would cause the extra characters at the end?
If I use the header('Location:'$url) method, the download is fine but I can't use that becuase I am unable to unlink the file.

Comment: Got it fixed. I had to remove the empty lines after the ?> tag at the end of my script.